# OpenGL; gluBuild2DMipmaps Invalid Enumerant

Tags: c++, opengl, mipmaps

I'm trying to implement mipmaps into an OpenGL Framework. After trying to use the tutorial at http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/mipmap_generation.html I've tried the following

```
for (int i=0;i<used_textures;i++)
{
        //glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
        GLGETERROR("Texture set up a");

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+i);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texhandles[i]);//bind texture - assume all are 2D
    GLGETERROR("Texture set up aa");
    for (int d=0;d<global_textures[i].depth;d++)
    {
        switch(global_textures[i].comp)
        {
        //There are 4 cases in the actual code but case 3 is the only one that is used based on the data file.
        case 3:
            //REMOVED  - glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D,  d, GL_RGB32F, global_textures[i].sx>>d, global_textures[i].sy>>d, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, global_textures[i].texMap[d] );
            gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 4, global_textures[i].sx >> d, global_textures[i].sy >> d, GL_RGB32F, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, global_textures[i].texMap[d]);
            break;

        }
    }
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
    //REMOVED - glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
    //REMOVED - glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );





}
```

in which the commented lines starting with REMOVED - are what I am removing to minmap instead as per the swiftless.com tutorial. The get error code is creating [this error window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYmmf.png), which to me seems like the error is in the glActiveTexture or the glBindTexture lines, yet I've only altered the code past that. For the second parameter in gluBuild2DMipmaps I've tried using d, 1,2,3 and 4 but I'm still not quite sure what it is that's meant to go in there.

Can anyone explain the invalid enumerant error and where I need to be looking to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happens most probably in the second iteration:

`GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR` is not a valid value for `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` since mipmapping can only help with minification, not with magnification. You should use `GL_NEAREST` or `GL_LINEAR` instead.

Comment: Thanks, it's rendering the box now. Quick follow up if you can see a glaring issue within the code i linked before, before the change it looked [like this](https://i.imgur.com/j9lcOQa.png) and with the mipmapping it looks like [this](https://i.imgur.com/WYGyUxD.png), with no texture no matter how zoomed in it is. Is that expected or have I messed something up elsewhere?